# How to customize response message in ModelViewSet

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I will send the request in post format using ModelViewSet and I will customize its response message. So I turned the response back on the perform_create method as shown in the following code, but it doesn't work as I want.

```
class CreateReadPostView (ModelViewSet) :
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    pagination_class = LargeResultsSetPagination

    def perform_create (self, serializer) :
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
        return Response({'success': '게시물이 저장 되었습니다.'}, status=201) # it's not work
```

How can I make this work normally? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the **`create(...)`** method

```
class CreateReadPostView(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    pagination_class = LargeResultsSetPagination

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return Response({'success': '게시물이 저장 되었습니다.'}, status=201)
```